# Plot lines in a lineplot in a different order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I generated a lineplot that looks like this:
[image]

The code used to generate it is:

```
library(ggplot2)

dp_no_sim_comparison_internal <- read.table("/home/agalvez/data/sims/final_output/internal_nodes/internal_dollop_final_output.csv", sep = "\t", header=TRUE)

dp_no_sim_comparison_internal$Node<-as.factor(dp_no_sim_comparison_internal$Node)

lineplot6 <- ggplot(dp_no_sim_comparison_internal, aes( x = Node, y = Present, group = Sim, colour = Sim)) +
  geom_line(alpha=0.1)  +
  xlab("Node ID") + ylab("Gene count") + ggtitle("Dollop") + labs(colour='Simulation') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "darkturquoise", high = "brown2")
  
lineplot6
```

In my graph, the blue lines are being plotted first, so they get kind of masked by the red ones, would it be possible to plot it in the reverse order?

Edit:
"dp_no_sim_comparison_internal" looks like:

```
> head(dp_no_sim_comparison_internal)
  Sim Node Present Gained Lost
1   1    1    2000   5000   NA
2   1    2    5000     NA   NA
3   2    1    1000     NA   NA
4   2    2    500      NA   NA
5   3    1    50       NA   NA
6   3    2    5000     NA   NA
7   4    1    5000     NA   NA
8   4    2    5        NA   NA
```

Comment: [This answer (potential duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69638762/903061) suggests you need to sort your data frame. Something like `dp_no_sim_comparison_internal = dp_no_sim_comparison_internal[order(-dp_no_sim_comparison_internal$Sim, dp_no_sim_comparison_internal$Node), ]`

Comment: This is also what Ithought but after sorting, it still prints the red lines on top...

Comment: Could you share a small reproducible example? 3 or 4 lines with 3 or 4 x values should be plenty.

Comment: Yes! I willl post it in the original question!

Comment: Do you just want the blue lines on top of the red lines, or do you want the lower Simulation lines on top of the higher Simulation lines? To get the first option, you can switch your color palette: `scale_color_gradient(low = "brown2", high = "darkturquoise")`

Comment: I want the lower Simulation lines on top of the higher ones!